# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am using `eclipse neon.3` version and `tomcat 8.5.15`,I tried to execute simple hello world program using spring mvc but I am getting this issue=>

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.

It happened only with spring mvc projects,rather than spring mvc,other codes executed successfully. Also mentioned the jar files which I  have uploaded.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Which solutions from SO have you tried? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the jars that are included in your build path?

Comment: commons-logging-1.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.springframework.asm.jar
org.springframework.beans.jar
org.springframework.context.jar
org.springframework.core.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.release.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet_3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: 1. Remove all the associated jars from everywhere (build path, lib folder etc)
2. Add the jar files only to the build path of the project as external jars.
sometimes, multiple files may conflict; so i suggest you to try this.

Comment: please give me all the required jar files which u r using in your projects....that will be helpful for me

Comment: shall i download source file or binary files????

Comment: Thank u  guys for your support.....code has been executed successfully....i  uploaded latest version on jar file....now its work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `javax.servlet-api.jar` in the classpath. Maybe it is not in tomcat's lib folder.
 Try to add this jar to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. To download a jar go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0

Comment: as per you said, i uploaded javax.servlet-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib directory as well as in tomcat's lib folder....still getting same exception....what to do now???

Comment: Have you added this jar to classpath in eclipse?

Comment: Also go to Project name -> Properties -> Targeted Runtimes and add your server

Comment: i have added in Libraries------ ryt click on project->properties->javabuildpath->labraries->add external jar.

Comment: i entered into Project name -> Properties -> Targeted Runtimes here i am getting right  tick besides my server

Comment: Try to put this jar into `Web App libraries` library.

Comment: In Targeted Runtimes select server which is listed there but if it is not listed click `New` button

Comment: how to do this...can u share the path for that....sorry to say but recently i am learning spring mvc.

Comment: In Targeted Runtimes, respective server is showing selected bydefault

Comment: In `Java build Path` click 'Add Library' -> select Web App libraries

Comment: ok..javax.servlet-api.jar file is already shown in Web App libraries.

Comment: Go to project properties -> deployment assembly and map Source `/webapp` to Deploy path `/`

Comment: you mean to say..instead of WEB-INF/classes i need to put WEB-INF/webapp in Deploy path?????

Comment: I am totally confused here because you said that you use spring mvc. Please give new question and provide all relevant files to show problem

Comment: see i unable to execute my code which is written in spring mvc format....u can preferred hello world example from tutorials point..same code i am going to execute..but getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.

Comment: Go to server folder where your project is deployed. Check if there is lib folder with .javax.servlet-api.jar.

Comment: Thank u  guys for your support.....code has been executed successfully....i  uploaded latest version on jar file....now its work.

Comment: This is very difficult to build spring mvc web app without Maven because you have to manually add all required jars

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I first tried to use Tomcat. If you imported `HttpServlet` class from `jakarta.servlet.http` try importing it from `javax.servlet.http` instead, that's what worked for me. 
Since I used `jakarta-servlet-api` dependency I expected to find the `HttpServlet` class in the `javax.servlet.http` package, however I was wrong. 
I extracted the `jakarta-servlet-api.jar` and saw that the package is called javax. 
So I imported HttpServlet from `javax.servlet.http` instead and it worked fine.